# Solving or estimating parameter values of $y_{t+1} = y_t + c\cdot (y_t)^a + x_t$

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, parameter-estimation

Consider we have a vector of observed data points $\mathbf{y}$ with $n$ elements. Each consecutive data point in $\mathbf{y}$ represents an observation made at a specific time $t$, let's say that at $t=1$ we have the first element $y(1)$, at $t=2$ we have the second element $y(2)$ and so on until $y(n)$ at $t=n$.

Let's assume we can describe the evolution of the data in the following way:

$y_{t+1} = y_t + c\cdot (y_t)^a + x_t$

where $c, a\in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ and $x_t$ is i.i.d. $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

**First**, suppose $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are known, what kind of approach should I use to compute or at least estimate the values for $c$ and $a$ ?

**Second**, now imagine we don't know $\mu$ and $\sigma$, how could i estimate them having $c$ and $a$ as unknowns still ? Really the major question for me here is how to deal with or solve functions that have random variables in them, also can this be said to be a differential equation with a random parameter.

I would appreciate any help on this, also if someone can point me in the right direction

Comment: Your notation is unclear to me. Do we have one fixed $x$ over time that is normally distributed? Moreover, what are $\psi$ and $x_{t}^{\omega}$.

Comment: @Marc $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector of data points, and for example $x_{t=1}$ is the first value in $\mathbf{x}$.$\psi$ and $\omega$ are two fixed valued parameters that i am trying to estimate, they describe non linearity in the system.

Comment: @Marc also, if you were referring to $x$ as in $x\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$, i am trying to say that we have a value $x$ sampled from a normal distribution, i am unsure if this is the best way to write, hence my third question, so please advise if you think i should write it differently to make it more clear

Comment: How about $x_{t}^{\omega}$?

Comment: @Marc so $x_t$ is a value from the data set at specific time $t$ and $x_t^\omega$ is that value to the power of $\omega$

Comment: The identity $$x_{t+1} = x_t + x\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma) + \psi \times x^\omega_t$$ is most unclear, you should concentrate on explaining it. Would you mean $$x_{t+1} = x_t + x$$ where $x-\psi x_t$ is independent of $(x_s)_{s\leqslant t}$ and $$x-\psi x_t\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)\ ?$$

Comment: @Did I have restructured the question, hopefully it can be better understood now. Let me know if there is still anything unclear, i am trying to write it the best i can.

Comment: To sum up, $$y_{t+1}=y_t+c\cdot(y_t)^a+x_t$$ where $c$ and $a$ are positive real numbers and $(x_t)$ is i.i.d. $\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, is this what you have in mind? (You will note I avoided to use the ultra-misleading symbol $\omega$ in a probabilistic context.)

Comment: @Did exactly, thank you for making it clearer, now i hope you can help me on this one or point me in the right direction. I am having a difficulty dealing with this because of the probabilistic term

Comment: The nonlinear term (unless $a=1$) makes it difficult. Oh, and b y the way, the recursion should read $$y_{t+1}=y_t+c\cdot|y_t|^a+x_t$$ since $y_t<0$ with positive probability.