# How to calculate threshold crossing probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

I am studying the evolution of a population in time, see figure below. I simulate $N=100$ different trajectories from time $t=0$ to $t=400$. When I compute the average of these trajectories at every time step I get the trajectory in represented in blue, and the point at which it crosses the criticality threshold of $0.5$ is shown in the figure as the vertical dashed black line.

I am especially interested in the time where the trajectories cross the criticality threshold of $0.5$ and want to **deal with the uncertainty** at which time the trajectory will cross the threshold.

How can I compute a PDF to represent such uncertainty over time? Is there any specific approach that anyone can recommend to do this ?

I want to use the empirical results, e.g. how many trajectories out of $N$ have crossed at times $t=0:500$

[image]

Comment: Could you say something about the calculation method of the grey trajectories?

Comment: It would be very useful indeed to include the details of your simulation procedure in your question.

Comment: This is a Gamma process added to a Gaussian process. In reality the model that represents the evolution of the data is a lot more complex and intractable. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2368917/solving-or-estimating-parameter-values-of-y-t1-y-t-c-cdot-y-ta-x-t

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your simulation is based on discrete time steps $t \in \{0,...,T\}$ (in your case $T = 400$).

Lets assume, that you run $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$ simulations, which gives you trajectories $s_1,...,s_n$, where each $$ s_i : \{0,...,T\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$
describes the value of the $i$-th simulation in dependence of time. So $s_i(t)$ would be the value of the $i$-th simulation at time $t$. Each $s_i$ describes exactly one of the grey lines in your plot. Now, for each $s_i$, you can compute a critical time point $$t_{\text{crit}}(s_i) := \min\{ t \in \{0,..,T\} \ \vert \ s_i(t) \geq c_{\text{crit}}    \} .$$ In your case, we have $c_{\text{crit}} = 0.5$.

We can see the values given by the expressions $t_{\text{crit}}(s_i)$ as $n$ independent realizations of a discrete random variable $$T_{\text{crit}} : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{N}_{\geq 0} .$$ If I understand your question correctly, then you are interested in estimating the probability distribution of $T_{\text{crit}}$.

Given the data you have obtained from computing the $t_{\text{crit}}(s_i)$, you can empirically estimate the probability mass function of $T_{\text{crit}}$ via $$ \Pr(T_{\text{crit}} = k) = \frac{\text{Number of elements in the set } \{ i \in \{1,...,n\} \ \vert \ t_{\text{crit}}(s_i) = k   \}}{n} $$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}$.

To get a reasonable estimate with this method, take care to choose $n$ as big as possible given your computational resources. Also, you have to choose $T$ big enough, so that all you $s_i$ (or at least almost all of them, you can ignore a few) actually exceed $c_{\text{crit}}$ at some time in $\{0,...,T\}$, because otherwise some of the expressions $t_{\text{crit}}(s_i)$ are the minimum of an empty set and do not exist.

In your plot, clearly your have to increase $T>>400$, in order to follow the method. If you cannot increase $T = 400$, you have to additionally consider the case that the critical value is never hit, but this only requires minor changes to the procedure I just described.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. I have already tried what you suggest, however something was bothering me, since the number of elements crossing the threshold would just increase, at a certain $T>>400$ all the trajectories would have passed the threshold and therefore the probability would be equal to 1. and to me this looks more like a CDF rather than a PDF is that correct ?

Comment: I don't see how this is a problem. If you increae $T$, then at some point all trajectories hit the critical value at some time $t<T$. This is to be expected for an increasing growth process like the one shown on your plot.
So of course the probability that your trajectory will hit the critical value at some(!) point will converge towards $1$. But the distribution of $T_{\text{crit}}$ will still be nontrivial (and won't be $1$ for any value $k$).